# Error al mostrar data desde un arreglo de objetos VueJS

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

Tengo un arreglo de objetos llamado materias y al intentar meterlo en un componente VueJS para luego mostrarlo me presenta un error:

```
<script>
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
  materias: []
},
created(){
var _this = this;
var url = "src/xmls/test.xlsx";
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", url, true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

oReq.onload = function(e) {
  var arraybuffer = oReq.response;
  /* convirtiendo data a binary string */
  var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
  var arr = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
  var bstr = arr.join("");
  /* Cargando XLSX */
  var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: "binary" });
  /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
  var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
  /* Get worksheet */
  var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
  materias = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { raw: true });
  _this = materias;
};
oReq.send();
}
})
</script>
```

Lo muestro de esta forma en mi sección template:

```
<template>
<div id="app">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <h1 class="text-center">Materias</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item text-center" v-for="(materia,$index) in materias">
          <span>{{ $index }} - Nombre: {{ materia.Curso }}</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Con las correcciones que se me indicaron abajo resolví un par de errores pero el de fondo que es que el componente vue reciba el arreglo persiste:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Mirando en la consola efectivamente la propiedad materias no esta definida en el componente, entonces no se porque mi arreglo no entra al componente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En la propiedad materias en vue `data` no tienes la clave `curso` solo tienes name y captched te falta y por eso te da el segundo error

Comment: al for en vez de poner `(materias,$index)` pon `(materia,$index)` puede que vue se este confundiendo entre el arreglo y cada uno de los items dentro de el

Comment: por eso creo te dan los 3 errores espero te ayude saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, en lo correspondiente a la clave curso no creo que vaya por ahi, ya que la clave nombre debe tomar su valor del campo Curso del arreglo, entonces al decir que es "undefined" por eso no la toma

Comment: creo que ya se donde esta el error es que tienes que poner tu function que genera el array dentro de la function reservada de vue `created(){tu funcion...}`

Comment: parar que genere el arreglo antes de todo y hay si pueda tomar los valores

Comment: La puse en beforeCreated y tampoco ha funcionado :(

Comment: revisa la respuesta a ver si te funciona la solucion saludos

Answer (score 0):

Buenas amigo espero te ayude el ejemplo la idea es hacer la petición Ajax dentro de la function `created()` de vue que cambia el valor de materias en el data saludos intente hacerlo lo mas parecido a tu problema

otra cosa importante es quitar el duplicado de id `id="app"` que tienes en el `html` eso hace conflicto entre la instancia de vue js

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    
    materias: []
      
   },
   created(){
   var _this = this

   $.ajax({
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
  method: 'GET'
  }).then(function(data) {
  // console.log(data)
  
    _this.materias = data
   })
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">

<div class="col-xs-12">
    <h1 class="text-center">Materias</h1>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item text-center" v-for="(materia,$index) in materias">
                <span>{{$index}} --   <b>Nombre:</b> {{materia.username}} - <b>Email:</b> {{materia.email}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Tengo un par de dudas que me gustaria que me aclararas, en la parte de Ajax no entiendo la funcion de root y en url me imagino que es mi arreglo, estoy bien?

Comment: la funcion de root ya la quite solo es de el API de prueba que use que es jsonplaceholder.typicode.com y la url es del API que me retorna unos usuarios al azar solamente

Comment: eso lo use para el ejemplo en tu caso usarias la url de tu php que retorna el array creo

Comment: Mi array sale de aqui: materias = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {raw:true}); todo se mantiene en JS no envio nada al servidor aun, entonces no tengo una ruta como tal sino la variable que lo contiene

Comment: bueno al parecer abres un documento en la url `"src/xmls/test.xlsx"` y le haces el tratamiento para crear el `array` pero esa funcionalidad tienes que ponerla dentro de el created y lo que retorne que sustitulla `this.materias`

Comment: Si, solicito un archivo excel en  [url = "src/xmls/test.xlsx"] y al pasarlo por la libreria guardo el array que me retorna en [materias = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {raw:true});] al ser una funcion que se ejecuta en el evento OnLoad del elemento XMLHttpRequest deberia ir dento o fuera de la funcion [$.ajax]?

Comment: no es necesaria en tu caso la function `$.ajax` solo agrega el contenido de la function no toda la function al `created()` que ejecuta todo lo que este dentro de el antes de todo

Comment: Muchas gracias, pude solucionar 2 de los 3 errores, pero se mantiene el de la no detección del arreglo, edite la pregunta con tus correcciones, te agradecería mucho si la miras.